# Unable to create initial connections of pool, Unable to obtain JDBC Connection errors

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I have a Spring Boot data JPA application where I am creating two data sources. I am getting this error when my application is booting up.

```
1. org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:253)
2. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:245)
    ... 88 more

3. Jan 20, 2020 7:39:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: null
[http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/orderForDateTopK/1/2] due to exception [Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection]
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)

4. Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)

5. Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Comment: Can your share your datasource configuration as well as the code that creates them?

Comment: @akortex91 you can find that here : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Yi30LUs3s7KrqyOBRIJfhdsVodzqY_-_

Comment: There are two Configuration files for two data source and application properties file were the jdbc urls and other details are mentioned.

Comment: please avoid sharing code like that. Edit your question to include all the information here.

Comment: I was not able to do it, so created files.

Comment: Have removed sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

You're using **Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool** for your datasource, but in your `application.properties` you configured **connection pool** for **Hikari** datasource.

Your `datasource` is not  instanced well, because of the **connection pool** settings.

your **wrong** configuration:

```
#HikariCP settings
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=15
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=1
```

---

**You have 2 solutions**

> 1- Change your connection pool **settings** from hikari to tomcat

like so

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=
//..
```

Some useful guide in this field :

**[Configuring a Tomcat Connection Pool](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-tomcat-connection-pool)**

> 2- Use **Hikari Connection Pool** instead of **tomcat** (Change datasource connection pool)

Some useful guide in this field :

**[A Simple Guide to Connection Pooling in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling)**

**[Introduction to HikariCP](https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp)**